# Find identical files in two folders with .Net

Tags: c#, .net

I have a folder with music videos which I want to backup from my laptop to a external hdd. I dont want to use a backup-Image, but a direct file copy so I can directly watch the music videos from the backup hdd on another computer/laptop or a console.

Curently I use the freeware SyncBack Free to mirror the files to the external hdd. SyncBack Free is a nice tool, but it does not seem to fully satisfy my needs. The problem is that I like to modify the filenames of my music videos from time to time. Though SyncBack Free has a option for files with identical content it does not seem to work for videos and you end up with two copies from the same file in each folder when you synchronise after a file name change.

So im thinking about writing my own freeware backup software.

The question is:
-how can I identify identical files with c#/.Net 4.0 without using the filename? Im thinking of generating hashes or a checksum for the files without knowing much about it
-Is it to slow to really be used for a backup software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a hash of a file like this

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;

static string GetFileHash(string filename)
{
    byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
    byte[] hash = MD5.Create().ComputeHash(data);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
}
```

MD5 is not the most secure hash, but it is still fast which makes it good for file checksums. If the files are large `ComputerHash()` also takes a `Stream`.

You may also want to check out some other check sum algorithms in the [HashLib](http://hashlib.codeplex.com/) library. It contains CRC and other algorithms which should be even faster. You can download it with nuget.

There are other strategies you can use as well such as checking if only the first x bytes are the same.

You can keep a database of hashes that have been backed up so that you don't have to recompute the hashes each time the backup runs. You could loop through only files which have been modified since the last backup time and see if their hash is in your hash database. SQLite comes to mind as a good database to use for this if you want your backup program to be portable.